# How to avoid repetitions of TapDown events in a CustomPainter when I hover over the Back button in Scaffold - or any other button?

Tags: hover, click, listener, repeat

I now have sample code, based on the example in the Listener API doco. It has an AppBar with icons, an empty CustomPainter canvas and a Column containing more icons. If you tap on the canvas area, you get one set of print() messages per hit. Fine. If you "hover" (with a mouse) over any of the icons in the AppBar or the Column, you get multiple spurious "hits" and repaints on the Canvas, even if you have not tapped anywhere. If you tap (or click) in an empty part of the AppBar or Column, you get no hit on the Canvas, as expected. What am I missing? Or is this perhaps a problem in the MacOS desktop version of Flutter and Dart? Code follows...

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Puzzle';

  final int index = 1;  // Simulate selection of puzzle from puzzle-list.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Create the list of action-icons.
    List<Widget> actionIcons = [
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.undo_outlined),
        tooltip: 'Undo a move',
        onPressed: () {
          print('PRESSED UNDO ******');
        },
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.redo_outlined),
        tooltip: 'Redo a move',
        onPressed: () {
          print('PRESSED REDO ******');
        },
      ),
    ];

    // Paint the puzzle-area with the action icons in a column on the RHS.
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(_title),
          // actions: actionIcons,      // Action-icons copy in AppBar.
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: MyStatefulWidget(index),
            ),
            Ink(
              color: Colors.amber.shade200,
              child: Column(
                children: actionIcons,  // Action-icons list.
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final int index;
  const MyStatefulWidget(this.index, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  Offset hitPos = Offset(-1.0, -1.0);
  late PuzzlePainter puzzlePainter;

  void _possibleHit(PointerEvent details)
  {
    setState(() {hitPos = details.localPosition;} );
    print('\n\nLISTENER: onPointerDown at ${hitPos.dx.toStringAsFixed(1)}, ${hitPos.dy.toStringAsFixed(1)}');
    // Tell the PuzzlePainter where the hit is and trigger a repaint.
    puzzlePainter.tapPos = hitPos;
    puzzlePainter.notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    int index = widget.index;
    puzzlePainter = new PuzzlePainter(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
      child: Listener(
        onPointerDown: _possibleHit,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: puzzlePainter,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PuzzlePainter extends ChangeNotifier implements CustomPainter {

  final int index;

  PuzzlePainter(this.index);

  Offset tapPos = Offset(-1.0, -1.0);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {  // Paint or re-paint the puzzle-area.
    Rect canvasRect = (Offset(0.0, 0.0) & size);
    print('Paint/Repaint Puzzle $index');

    // Paints (and brushes/pens) for areas and lines.
    var paint1 = Paint()        // Background colour of canvas.
      ..color = Colors.amber.shade100
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    // Paint the background of the canvas.
    canvas.drawRect(canvasRect, paint1);

    if (canvasRect.contains(tapPos)) {
      print('HIT at $tapPos in $canvasRect');
    }
    else {
      print('NO HIT: $tapPos not in $canvasRect');
    }

  } // End void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size)

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PuzzlePainter oldDelegate) {
    print('ENTERED PuzzlePainter shouldRepaint()');
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool? hitTest(Offset position) => true;

  // Dummy methods: needed because we are re-implementing CustomPainter (above).
  get semanticsBuilder => null;

  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

A few days ago, I wrote...

I am trying to learn Flutter and Dart and at the same time transcribe a Puzzle application that I made major contributions to a few years ago. That app is programmed in C++ and uses the Qt and KDE libraries. My long-term aim is to make the app fully portable across all desktops and devices supported by Flutter and Dart. Currently I am working on an Apple MacBook with MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, but I have access to other Apple devices. The original app is a desktop app, with menus, toolbars, buttons, icons, etc. but I am aiming to simplify that UI considerably.

I started developing with the Flutter command's skeleton template. So far my app has three screens: a Menu or Home screen, in which a user selects the type, size and difficulty of a puzzle he wishes to solve (think jigsaws, mazes, etc.), a Settings screen and a Puzzle screen. The Menu is working quite well, using Flutter's ListView. The Settings screen is still in skeleton form. The Puzzle screen is where I am having problems.

Most of the screen is occupied by a Canvas which accepts TapDown or mouse-click events, nothing fancy, so I am wrapping my puzzle-painter in a Listener rather than a GestureDetector. Everything goes fine as long as I keep the pointer within the puzzle-area. I get one TapDown event per tap or click and these taps control the placement of symbols, one at a time, for the user to work towards a solution of the puzzle that is displayed. Now I have added a narrow column of IconButtons at the right of the Canvas area. Three examples are Undo, Redo and Hint buttons.

When I move the pointer over one of these buttons, so as to tap or click it, the last TapDown event that occurred in the Canvas is triggered multiple times, causing bursts of 8 or 9 spurious repaints of the Canvas. This happens regardless of whether I actually decide to click the IconButton. It also happens if I move the pointer over the Back button in Scaffold's AppBar, so I do not think it is the coding of my home-grown icon bar that is causing the problem. Also I have not coded Listener.onPointerHover, so where could these signals be coming from?

If I move the pointer into my window's Title Bar or out of the window altogether, I get similar repetitions of TapDown events. I have seen these before I added the code for the IconButtons, but thought maybe they were a teething problem of Flutter's desktop implementation.

By the way, window-resizing and re-drawing of my Puzzles is ultra-fast and smooth!

I would like to show some code and am working on a bare-bones version of the Puzzle screen, using the sample code in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html as a guide. But whatever I do the spurious events keep happening.

---

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help to structure your question. That will increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand where you are coming from. The code I have supplied is "reprex" and "mcve" IMHO. It is a complete Flutter app and is minimal except that it uses a List of two IconButtons and passes an int parameter down the chain to the State and paint() re-implementations, in case these features have a bearing on the problem.

Comment: The first para of my post describes what happens when the code is run. Keep an eye on print-messages in your console area. First click on the empty canvas, then move to hover over an IconButton. Then you should get multiple re-paints of the canvas, and multiple print-messages, even though you have not tapped anywhere. I am not sure if this will happen on a phone or tablet. I am using an Apple laptop.

Comment: I think the problem may be that IconButtons have tooltips and InkResponse splash effects and these trigger repaints in Flutter, perhaps of the entire screen or window. If I make the IconButtons' Column a lot wider, nothing happens until I hover close enough to a button to trigger one of those effects.